# Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of X changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, systemctl

I am running Debian 10.4 on kernel 4.19.66+.

It seems that my unit files are changing on their own (It sounds crazy, I know), with no interaction from me, the only user of the system.

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/855042/how-do-i-know-if-systemctl-daemon-reload-needs-to-be-run/855048) user, who was trying to determine what changed in their unit files. I ran `for var in $(systemctl | grep running | awk '{print $1}'); do systemctl status $var | grep "changed on disk" | grep ".service"; done` to see what files had been changed, out of curiosity, and found

1. dhcpcd.service
2. getty@tty1.service
3. systemd-timesyncd.service

among 2 other files (services I created) that had changed. I did not make any changes, in fact I was completely unaware of the getty.service before seeing this. I believe these are related to outages I have had.

How can I track down the cause for this warning?

Comment: I see this all the time, running `systemctl --user daemon-reload` or `systemctl daemon-reload` never fixes it...